# Secure Connection to Oracle Database from within Container

Tags: oracle, docker, dockerfile, oracle19c

I'm connecting to an Oracle datebase using an encrypted connection. I don't use a wallet and all I need to provide for the connection to be established is my company's root certificate. This works locally.

I'd like to connect to that same database from within a container.

Oracle provides an image with Oracle Client Libraries already installed and when I use that image I can also connect to the database when I also import the root certificate, i.e.

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 ghcr.io/oracle/oraclelinux8-instantclient:21

COPY my_root_ca.pem /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/
RUN update-ca-trust

ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/sh"]
```

All I do to test the connection is run sqlplus. That Oracle-image is based on a Fedora/RHEL6 distro and I'd like to use another base image for my actual code. The Oracle-image already contains the instant client and sql*plus so I'll have to add both to my image. The base image I'm using in my "custom" build is a debian so the path to import the root certificate is also different from the fedora build (I looked up the paths here: https://serverfault.com/a/722646/971785).

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 debian:bookworm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ca-certificates curl unzip libaio1

# oracle instant client (client libraries)
RUN curl -OJL https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/2112000/instantclient-basic-linux.x64-21.12.0.0.0dbru.zip
RUN unzip instantclient-basic-linux.x64-21.12.0.0.0dbru.zip && rm instantclient-basic-linux.x64-21.12.0.0.0dbru.zip

# sqlplus
RUN curl -OJL https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/2112000/instantclient-sqlplus-linux.x64-21.12.0.0.0dbru.zip
RUN unzip instantclient-sqlplus-linux.x64-21.12.0.0.0dbru.zip && rm instantclient-sqlplus-linux.x64-21.12.0.0.0dbru.zip

RUN echo /instantclient_21_12 > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient.conf
RUN ldconfig

COPY my_root_ca.pem /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
RUN update-ca-certificates

ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/sh"]
```

When I run `sqlplus` now in the debian build I get an error

> ORA-28759: failure to open file

which usually indicates that Oracle is looking for a wallet (which I, indeed, did not provide).

I'm missing something in my custom built image but I can't see what's different from the image Oracle is providing. When I look up the error code people suggest creating a wallet but I did not need to create the wallet with the Oracle image (similar to any Java apps where I simply import the root certificate into a JKS).